# Interpreting Goodness-of-fit resutls (McFadden vs Lipsitz Test)

Tags: goodness-of-fit, ordered-logit

I am trying to do goodness-of-fit for an ordinal model namely, proportional odds regression (PO). I performed PO on two sets of data (data A, data B) to compare McFadden and Lipsitz test results.

We know that McFadden Pseudo R squared is presented by: 
R^2=1-  (Log(L_c) )/(Log(L_null)).
If the model predictability is bad (close to the predictability of the null model-"constant-only" model), then McFadden goes to zero. As we will see from Data B (McFadden R^2 = 0.0059).

On the other hand, when I use Data A, the model shows association between the dependent and independent variables. In this case, we also see better McFadden value (R^2 = 0.32). All this makes sense to me. However, when I use (Lipsitz Test) to evaluate my model(s) performance, I get confused.

According to https://www.jstor.org/stable/2986153  (precisely in section 4, the example), high p-value from Lipsitz test indicates good correlation between predicted and observed values. This means model is has good predictability.

I got very small p-value from Data A (where McFadden R^2 was better), and I got high p-value (0.81) from Data B (where McFadden R^2 was small).

Here is my two sets of data

```
#Data A: 
SatA=c(rep("Low",100),rep("Medium",150),rep("High",20)
,rep("Low",20),rep("Medium",30),rep("High",180))
InflA =c(rep("Low",20),rep("Medium",80),rep("High",30)
,rep("Low",120),rep("Medium",18),rep("High",2),
rep("Low",20),rep("Medium",30),rep("High",150),rep("Low",30))
ContA=c(rep("Low",270),rep("High",230))
ModelA = polr(as.factor(SatA)~InflA+ContA,Hess = TRUE)
exp(cbind(OR = coef(ModelA), confint.default(ModelA)))
pR2(ModelA)
lipsitz.test(ModelA)

#Data B
ModelB <- polr(Sat ~ Infl  + Cont +Freq, data = housing)
exp(cbind(OR = coef(ModelB), confint.default(ModelB)))
pR2(ModelB)
lipsitz.test(ModelB)
```

What am I doing wrong? I greatly appreciate any reading sources and hints.